# C# enum scope. visible only with in function

Tags: c#, enums, scope

in C#, is it possible to declare an Enum that is only visible within the function where I will be using it?

Comment: You can use constants within function - perhaps that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums have the same scoping rules as classes. You can't declare them inside a function, though you can declare them private to a class:

```
public class Foo {
  private enum Bar { A, B, C }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. An enum needs to be declared within a namespace or class, thus it will always have scope beyond the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

With in that `class` you can make. I don't think so you can make visible only to a particular `function`.